# How to change yeoman config to run livereload properly

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, grunt-contrib-watch

I have `Gruntfile.js` config for my AngularJs app generated by Yeoman. I've changed protocol to https. So it now serves all files on https://localhost:9000.

```
... 
connect: {
   options: {
      port: 9000,
      protocol: 'https',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      livereload: 35729,
      ...
```

So it now serves all files on https://localhost:9000/. I've also added cert & key to livereload config:

```
  livereload: {
       options: {
             key: grunt.file.read('livereload.key'),
             cert: grunt.file.read('livereload.crt'),
```

But It's still not loading livereload.js from [*https*://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1](https://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1) `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` I can open http connection and load livereload.js in browser at [*http*://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1](http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1)

What should I change to serve livereload.js on https?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. And finally I figured out how to set it up in Angular-generator.

Under grunt.initConfig.connect.options, replace the "livereload: 35729" with the following setting:

```
livereload: {
                port: 35729,
                key: grunt.file.read('livereload.key').toString(),
                cert: grunt.file.read('livereload.crt').toString(),
            },
```

Since the Gruntfile is using the setting reference for the watches, we can set from the original place.

After this setting, I also added `<script src="https://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` in my html file and use htmlprocess to remove it from the release build.

Hope it helps.

Cheers,

Peng

Answer (score 0):

First:(inside connect.options object)

```
livereload: true || port(default is 35729)  <-- this inject the html snipet in index
```

After change this: (inside the watch object)

```
js : {
   files  : ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
   tasks  : ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
   options: {
      livereload: {
          port: 35729,
          key : grunt.file.read('./certs/server.key').toString(),
          cert: grunt.file.read('./certs/server.crt').toString(),
      }
   }
}
```

and this:

```
livereload: {
    options: {
        livereload: {
            port: 35729,
            key : grunt.file.read('./certs/server.key').toString(),
            cert: grunt.file.read('./certs/server.crt').toString(),
         }
     },
     files  : [
         '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
         '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
     ]
}
```

Or you can define a config object:

```
lr: {
        port: 35729,
        key : grunt.file.read('./certs/server.key').toString(),
        cert: grunt.file.read('./certs/server.crt').toString(),
    },
```

and use that like this:

```
js : {
    files  : ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks  : ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
    options: {
       livereload: '<%= lr %>'
    }
}
```